# Getting data from Json url using CURL Returning NULL

Tags: php, json, curl

i have a JSON link , i want to get data from it but it is returning NULL.

**Code:**

```
$url = 'https://cheddargetter.com/json/customers/search/orderBy/id/orderByDirection/asc/perPage/100/';

//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
//var_dump(json_decode($result, true));                                                                                              

echo '<pre>abc'. print_r($result) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

your code looks correct. the problem is the url. I guess it ask for authentication to get the json data.

```
https://cheddargetter.com/?fwd=%2Fjson%2Fcustomers%2Fsearch%2ForderBy%2Fid%2ForderByDirection%2Fasc%2FperPage%2F100%2F#login
```

Comment: but this link is generated by ChadderGetter itself

Comment: I agree. If you access to that URL through the browser, it should return JSON, instead, it redirects to their website. It means some kind of validation like an API key is missing.

Comment: how to authenticate in this link?

Comment: I haven't found any way to Authenticate using this link

Comment: https://cheddargetter.com/developers#format - it uses `HTTP Basic Authentication` . Just google on how to do that using php/Curl